# Special Characters are not being processed from ASP.NET pages deployed on SharePoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2007, oracle10g, special-characters

I am facing a weird issue with Asp.net Pages deployed on SharePoint 2007. We have some custom pages developed for our application.The application pages are developed using Asp.net and C#, we have few text boxes in the asp.net page. when the user types in some special characters like ™(Trade Mark) or ®(Registered Mark) and tried to save it to database. The data in the text box like ™ or ® is inserted as ? (Question Mark).

But when the same C# application is run from the local it is inserting the special characters into the oracle database(Same server). Can anyone please help me in finding why this is not working when the pages are deployed on SharePoint server.

Comment: I'd set up some logging for your application, to see whether (when deployed) the bad encoding happens before you insert the values to the database, or after.

Comment: Can you please tell me what kind of logging should i need to setup?

Comment: Does your application already have any kind of logging enabled? To file, Windows event log, database, etc? If so, you could just use that mechanism. Just before you insert the data to the database, output some log messages including the data which is to be persisted. You can then see whether it has already been encoded to ????'s. If so - then you can know for sure the problem is happening in your code. It is then a matter of logging in various places until you narrow in on the area of code which is being problematic.

Comment: we dont have any logging mechanism in place. As we are only site adminsitrators we only have access to physical folder where we can copy our asp.net pages and dll related to our application. IS there any other way to debug this on sharepoint server?

Comment: Well, in the absence of a logging framework, the code which compiles to your DLLs could write to a textfile - that is a very simple way of logging. You can also just write out to the page - quick and dirty - assuming that your site is not public facing.

Comment: It's definitely an encoding problem. Ensure that all the processes, libraries, and methods use strings that are UTF-8 when sending data back and forth.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Actually on a insert button click the c# functions are using Insert Statements to save the data to the oracle database. Can you please provide me with a snippet of code on how to log the processing details into the text file? And also do i need to save the text file (used for logging) on the server after the processing?

Comment: Hi Jon, It looks like you are correct. But we are not able to see this issue when we run our code on our local machines. This is only evident when we run our application through sharepoint. Can you please help me on how to troubleshoot this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is any help but [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joelo/archive/2007/06/27/file-name-length-size-and-invalid-character-restrictions-and-recommendations.aspx) is a list of characters restricted by SharePoint